# Register extension and create shortcut

Tags: android, android-manifest

I register file extensions in my android video player app in manifest, through following code:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gp" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mkv" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.webm" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zrp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This works fine, however when app is installed, shortcut is not created. If I remove this part from manifest, shortcut is created normally:

```
<data android:scheme="file" />
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
<data android:host="*" />
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish both: register extensions and create shortcut?

Comment: could you try this @Griberg https://androidsolved.wordpress.com/2015/07/11/how-to-create-android-app-home-shortcut/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. However, I don't look for programmatic solution on adding shortcut, but manifest tag form that will allow both register extensions and shortcut creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have separated the same code in 2  tags, like this:

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.3gp" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mkv" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.webm" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zrp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```